# Google Form Email Notification On Submission

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to update this script to allow me to update the "Sender's" or "Reply To" email address. I'm unsure how to do this as I'm using the script listed here - http://www.labnol.org/?p=20884

I've emailed the developer of this script but have yet to receive a response. Any advice on adding a field to overwrite the default "Reply To" or sender email address?

Thanks for your help!

```js
/* Send Google Form by Email v2.0 */
    /* For customization, contact the developer at amit@labnol.org */
    /* Tutorial: http://www.labnol.org/?p=20884 */
    function Initialize() {
    var triggers = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers();
    for(var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendGoogleForm")
    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
    }
    function SendGoogleForm(e)
    {
    try
    {
    // You may replace this with another email address
    var email = "CLIENT EMAIL ADDRESS";
    // Optional but change the following variable
    // to have a custom subject for Google Form email notifications
    var subject = "Form Application Submitted";
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var columns = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var message = "";
    // Only include form fields that are not blank
    for ( var keys in columns ) {
    var key = columns[keys];
    if ( e.namedValues[key] && (e.namedValues[key] != "") ) {
    message += key + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[key] + "\n\n";
    }
    }
    // This is the MailApp service of Google Apps Script
    // that sends the email. You can also use GmailApp for HTML Mail.
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
    } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
```

with

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {replyTo: "abc@example.com", from: "xyz@example.com"});
```

The from address has to be an alias though.